# Subprocess wait() function doesn't seem to be waiting for the subprocess to complete

Tags: python, subprocess, wait

I'm trying to run a php script with python's subprocess module.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['php', '-f', test.php], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

retCode = proc.wait

print retCode

val = float(kprocess.stdout.read())

return val
```

I've also tried:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['php', '-f', test.php], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

val = float(kprocess.communicate()[0])

return val
```

Both ways work locally when I just run it in a python interpreter, however when I try to run it on the actual server, I always get "ValueError at / empty string for float()". This leads me to believe that the process is somehow not being waited for. What am I missing?

EDIT: I'm using Django, so it only seems to break when I run with Django.

Answer (score 5):

You have to actually call the processes' [`wait`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) function:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(...)
retCode = proc.wait # retCode will be the function wait
retCode = proc.wait() # retCode will be the return code
```

However, since you are redirecting the output to, you should heed the warning in the `wait` docs and use [`communicate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) instead. Make sure your code is free of syntactic errors:

- `test.php` is probably not a variable name, but a string
- You're confusing two variable names, `proc` and `kprocess`
- You're blindly parsing the result of `communicate` (This is not strictly an error, but can hinder error detection and tracing)

Instead, I'd suggest:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['php', '-f', 'test.php'],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,stderr = proc.communicate()
if proc.returncode != 0:
    raise Exception('Test error: ' + stderr)
return float(stdout)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry about the syntactical issues, I was trying to "paraphrase" my actual code and got mixed up. In any case, the problem seemed to be some path issues with test.php, it's been resolved now. Thanks!